# проблема с appendChild()

Tags: javascript

Вот мой код:

```js
function f1(){
    var a = document.getElementById("text");
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    var c = a.cloneNode(true);
    p.appendChild(c);
    var b = document.getElementsByClassName("favourite")[0];
    b.appendChild(p);

    localStorage.setItem("mytext", a.innerHTML);
}

document.getElementsByClassName("favourite")[0].innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("mytext");
```

```css
.favourite{
    background-color: red;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
}

.one{
    background-color: green;
    width: 20px;
    height:10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">Some long text...</div><button onclick="f1()">Add</button>
<div class="favourite"></div>
```

При нажатии на кнопку "Add", текст добавляется в див `class="favourite"` столько раз, сколько пользователь нажмет на кнопку. Как сделать так что бы текст добавился только один раз? И ещё один вопрос - Я хочу сделать много таких дивов похожих на тот что я написала выше, они будут отличаться текстом, правильно ли я сделаю, если к каждому событию буду добавлять одну и ту же функцию `f1()` Ведь тогда код будет длинным.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> >> Правильно ли я сделаю...

Да, но удобнее сразу из скрипта повесить обработчики на все кнопки.

`this` указывает на элемент, который вызвал функцию (на который кликнули). И для данной разметки, text[i] можно было заменить на `this.previousElementSibling`

```js
let add = document.querySelectorAll('.add');
let text = document.querySelectorAll('.text');
let fav = document.querySelector('.favourite');

for (let i = 0; i < add.length; i++) {
  add[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.disabled = true;
 // this.style.display = "none";
    let p = create('p');
    let c = text[i].cloneNode(true);
    text[i].classList.add('active'); // Например. Или display: none;
    
    p.appendChild(c);
    fav.appendChild(p);
    // localStorage.setItem("mytext", fav.innerHTML);
  });
}

function create(ele){
  return document.createElement(ele);
}
```

```css
.favourite {
  background-color: #ffe2aa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.one {
  background-color: green;
  width: 20px;
  height: 10px;
}

.bubu { display: flex; }
.add { margin: 0 5px; }
.text { color: red; }
.text.active { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="bubu">
  <span class="text">111</span><button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="text">222</span><button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="text">333</span><button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="text">444</span><button class="add">+</button>
  <span class="text">555</span><button class="add">+</button>
</div>

<div class="favourite"></div>
```